# Evidence of/against deterioration in language proficiency

Tags: language-change, applied-linguistics, literacy

The opinion that young people nowadays can't properly write any more seems to have (had) currency across many cultures and times. For example, [C. H. Ward](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC8QtwIwAA&url=http://www.ted.com/talks/john_mcwhorter_txtng_is_killing_language_jk.html&ei=ryvxUcP-BITWtQbcgYHoBA&usg=AFQjCNGVpMKeiaqJpmOUeHcum4mxhQOcxg&sig2=VGBQt9pdCQJw1S_rqRU88A&bvm=bv.49784469,d.Yms), a 1917 Conneticut school teacher, is reported as saying that

> From every college in the country goes up the cry, "Our freshmen can't spell, can't punctuate." Every high school is in disrepair because its pupils are so ignorant of the merest rudiments.

**Q: I was wondering whether there is any evidence of developments in (written) language proficiency** of, say, 18 year-olds, in post-WW2 industrial societies.

Before WW2 and in pre-industrial societies I assume public education was still expanding and following from that there was an increase in literacy. So in the general population I suppose there will also have been an increase in language proficiency and writing skills. I chose 18 years as a baseline because I assume that is the general school-leaving age for upper secondary education, but it's just an approximation.

I would be particularly interested in data on different languages (English, French, German, ...) and the general population, but college freshmen would also do. I suppose any or most available data will be on proficiency in (written) standard language, not non-standard dialects.

**Possible sources** include standardised school-leaving exams like the US-American SAT. These can and are sometimes said to be subject to grade inflation - General improvement in scores might be due to more lenient grading or easier tasks. Are there other sources not/less subject to this criticism?

**Motivation for asking:** In case this helps in answering the question, I am tired of listening to complaints about how children and young adults can't spell any more, our language is going to the dogs etc. The fact that such complaints are not new suggests that they are not based on facts. I would like to be able to point out that, in fact, language proficiency has remained stable or even improved for some time. If there is evidence to the contrary I'll do my best to hide... ehm I'll eat my words.

Comment: You're confusing literacy with language proficiency. They're not the same thing at all. Literacy is what's taught in schools. Language proficiency is learned by talking and listening. It is possible, but not common, to learn both together, especially in Anglophone schools, since students there are expected to be native speakers of English and learn nothing else about the language itself. All instruction is on literacy in English, concerned with minor details like spelling and punctuation, and zombie grammar rules which nobody understands but everybody's scared of.

Comment: When talking about proficiency in standard language, I don't think it's possible to factor out the influence of literacy on language proficiency. Those who practice reading and writing increase their capability to master educated standard language, both in terms of lexis and written grammar. Also, standard language is (in the case of many languages and their speakers) mostly taught in schools while acquisition of the native dialect occurs outside schools. And I don't think it's always useful to restrict 'language proficiency' to spoken language.

Comment: To the extent that there is any such thing as a "standard language", this might be true. But there is no evidence that it is the case; indeed, there is evidence that mastery of lexis and written grammar has declined considerably over the last century. See, for instance, the [London English Matriculation Exam from 1899](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/1899MatriculationExam.pdf); this is what you were expected to know to **get into** college.

Comment: That's an interesting document, thanks (+1). You seem to imply that the questions in this exam are a lot harder than in equivalent exams today. Could it be that just the type of questions they were asking was different (knowledge of Latin and history of English, explanation of grammatical terms)? Or do you think that the papers written in the exams were better in the sense that they were more eloquent and conformed to educated written English?

Comment: I think 99% of honors college graduates in English would fail. I can't say about the quantity of the papers written a century ago; I do have some experience with the quality of papers written during the last half-century, and they're not all that great. But it's not the quality of the writing that's significant here -- that's subjective anyway. No, what I find interesting is that they were expected to know  facts about their language, and to integrate them into an essay, instead of just checking boxes. They actually had to know and to think about language. That doesn't happen nowadays.